# Data mapper saves last element only from cycle

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Will save last element. You can run script 17 times and save everything. What happen?!

```
class Cities
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :header, String
  default_scope(:default).update(:order => [:id.desc])
end

@countries = [ "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bengaluru", "Hyderabad", "Ahmedabad", "Accra", "Kumasi", "Lagos", "Kano", "Ibadan", "Beijing", "Shanghai", "Guangzhou", "Hangzhou", "Chongqing", "Wuhan" ]

c = Cities.new

@countries.each { |x| 
 c.header = x
 c.save
}
```

Comment: Try it yourself. May be I have bad ruby? :))))

Answer (score 0):

Since `c` is initialized outside the loop, you are just overwriting the same object again and again.

Solution is to move `c` initialization inside the loop, like this:

```
@countries.each { |x|
  c = Cities.new
  c.header = x
  c.save
}
```

or simply just:

```
@countries.each { |x|
  Cities.create!(header: x)
}
```

Also your model name should be singular, not plural. So you should name it `City` instead of `Cities`.

Plus, make your loop variable name more descriptive, so instead of `x` maybe call it `country`.